# How can I modify every string in a list based on a character in each string?

Tags: python

For example, emails have "@" symbols in all of them.

```
lst = ["johndoe@example.com","doejohn@email.com","maryjane@domain.com"]
```

How could I replace all the text after "@" when they vary in character count? My goal would be to get a new list such as:

```
newlist = ["johndoe@changed.com", "doejohn@changed.com", "maryjane@changed.com"]
```

Comment: Use regex in a loop `re.sub(r'@[a-z]+', '@changed')`

Comment: careful using `list` as a variable name btw, it is a keyword

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ["johndoe@example.com", "doejohn@email.com", "maryjane@domain.com"]

out = [i.split("@")[0] + "@changed.com" if "@" in i else i for i in lst]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['johndoe@changed.com', 'doejohn@changed.com', 'maryjane@changed.com']
```

---

Note: for more advanced use-cases, I recommend to look at [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

Comment: Is there a method in `re` for replacement within lists? Or would it be a loop?

Comment: @RichieV No, I'm not aware of such method. It needs to be done through loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` which will return an array of strings either side of the symbol.

```
list = ["johndoe@example.com","doejohn@email.com","maryjane@domain.com"]
split_list = []

for email in list:
    split_email = email.split("@")
    split_list.append(split_email[0] + "@changed.com")

print(split_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex, or you can use [.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) in this particular example:

```
lst = ["johndoe@example.com","doejohn@email.com","maryjane@domain.com"] 

>>> [lh+sep+'changed.com' for lh,sep,rh in (s.partition('@') for s in lst)]
['johndoe@changed.com', 'doejohn@changed.com', 'maryjane@changed.com']
```

If the `'@'` is possibly not in the string, and you would not want those strings modified, you can do:

```
[lh+sep+'changed.com' if sep else lh 
     for lh,sep,rh in (s.partition('@') for s in lst)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: use a regex (regular expression). These use the re library.

Option 2: do it a little more pythonically, by looping through the list and splitting the string into a domain and info section, and then setting the domain as "changed.com". Like so:

```py
emails = ["aperson@email.com", "another@example.org", "onemore@something.net"]
new = [email.split("@")[0]+"@newone.com" for email in emails]
```

This uses something called a list comprehension, which is a really good python feature. It makes a list called `new` which stores every item of `email` with a domain ending.

You could make a function like this:

```
def new_domain(emails,domain):
     return [email.split("@")[0]+"@"+domain for email in emails]
```

This means you can use it whenever you have a list of emails you want to change the ending of:

```
>>> emails = ["johndoe@example.com","doejohn@email.com","maryjane@domain.com"] 
>>> new_domain(emails,"changed.com")
["johndoe@changed.com", "doejohn@changed.com", "maryjane@changed.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python slices to slice off the part of each email between `'@'` and `'.'`, and use the `replace` method to replace the slice with the desired domain:

```
lst = ["johndoe@example.com","doejohn@email.com","maryjane@domain.com"]

lst = [e.replace(e[e.find('@')+1:e.find('.')], 'changed') for e in lst]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['johndoe@changed.com', 'doejohn@changed.com', 'maryjane@changed.com']
```

This method will come in handy if not all the email address end with `'.com'`, for example, some ends with `'.ca'`.

Answer (score 0):

Although `split()` and regular expressions make sense as the problem gets more complex, for the probem as described, we can simply use `index()`:

```
lst = ["johndoe@example.com", "doejohn@email.com", "maryjane@domain.com"]

newlst = [address[:address.index('@')] + "@changed.com" for address in lst]

print(newlst)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
['johndoe@changed.com', 'doejohn@changed.com', 'maryjane@changed.com']
>
```